# Braintree Android: Tokenization Key or Client Token was invalid

Tags: braintree-sandbox

I am trying to implement the Braintree Api in my Android app but when i send the generated client token which I receive from my Server and send it to Drop-In UI then I am getting "Tokenization Key or Client Token was Invalid". Whereas the same ClientToken mechanism in working in our Website. Is there any setttings changes required in my account?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was not adding the tokenization key due to which i was getting the prompt.
After adding the tokenization key, it works fine.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Where did you get the tokenization key from?